# Generic methods in SpringBatch's Step chunk

Tags: java, generics, syntax, spring-batch

I am actually using Spring Batch and I have been asking myself some questions about generic methods. Considering the following piece of code:

```
public <I, O> SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk(int chunkSize) {
    return new SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>(this).chunk(chunkSize);
}
```

If we check inside the source, a little bit further, we encounter:

```
public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> reader(ItemReader<? extends I> reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
    return this;
}
```

I unterstand by chaining the calls like this:

```
@Bean
public Step step(final AccountReader accountReader, final AccountProcessor accountProcessor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT, Account>chunk(10)
            .reader(accountReader)
            .processor(accountProcessor)
            .writer(new JsonWriter<>())
        .build();
}
```

That the `reader()` method will require an `ItemProcessor<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>`

I found this kind of cool to preserve type safety.

Now my problem. Given the following code:

```
@Component
public class ItemDictionary {

    private final Map<Class, ItemReader> itemReaders;

    @Autowired
    public ItemDictionary(final List<ItemReader> readers) {
        itemReaders = readers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ItemReader::getClass,
                Function.identity()
        ));

    public <I> ItemReader<I> getReader(final Class clazz) {
        return itemReaders.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

I wanted to define the `Step` defined above like this:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT, Account>chunk(10)
            .reader(<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>itemDictionary.getReader(AccountReader.class))
            .processor(accountProcessor)
            .writer(new JsonWriter<>())
        .build();
}
```

`itemDictionary` is basically a Map containing all of the `ItemReader` implementations present in my Spring context.

This call `<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>itemDictionary.getReader(AccountReader.class)` is rejected by the compilator as an `illegal start of expression`

Am I missing something ?

Is it still possible to preserve type safe check using `ItemDictionnary` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is actually wrong in java.

You can't preserve type safety here because you already loose it when you store your implementations to `private final Map<Class, ItemReader> itemReaders`

I would suggest that simplest solution will be doing type cast:

```
(ItemReader<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>) itemDictionary.getReader(AccountReader.class)
```

Or we can thin about it further if you will explain what `COR_ACC_ACCOUNT` is. I have feeling that this is a generic type, right?

```
    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT, Account>chunk(10)
            .reader((ItemReader<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>) itemDictionary.getReader(AccountReader.class))
            .processor(accountProcessor)
            .writer(new JsonWriter<>())
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: This COR_ACC_ACCOUNT is simply a POJO with a weird name, I admit. It holds data coming from a database, that's all. There is no generic type involved.

Comment: I've checked your example and actually after removing `<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>` it was working well without any compilation errors or warnings.

Comment: In fact, this is the right solution. Could you please update your answer so that I can validate it ?

Answer (score 1):

According to `.<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT, Account>chunk(10)`, the type of items to read is `COR_ACC_ACCOUNT`, so `AccountReader` should return items of this type, in which case you don't need the cast here:

`.reader(<COR_ACC_ACCOUNT>itemDictionary.getReader(AccountReader.class))`

I tried your example and I don't have a compilation error:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemDictionary itemDictionary() {
        return new ItemDictionary(Arrays.asList(new FooReader()));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Bar> itemWriter() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Foo, Bar>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemDictionary().getReader(Foo.class))
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public class ItemDictionary {

        private Map<Class, ItemReader> itemReaders;

        public ItemDictionary(final List<ItemReader> readers) {
            itemReaders = readers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    ItemReader::getClass,
                    Function.identity()
            ));
        }

        public <I> ItemReader<I> getReader(final Class clazz) {
            return itemReaders.get(clazz);
        }

    }

    class Foo { }

    class Bar { }

    class FooReader implements ItemReader<Foo> {

        @Override
        public Foo read() {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.